# Allocating array size inside struct from user input in C

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

I'm recently working on a project in C. I have a requirement to allocate an array inside a struct and its size need to be obtained from the user. But because of specific requirements, I cannot use pointers and then allocate memory using malloc.

My code is as follows:

```
#define arraySize size

typedef struct sample{
    int keys[arraySize]
    int pointers[arraySize + 1]
} sample;

int main(){
   //size should be obtained from user input
   size  = 15;
}
```

If the struct is defined inside main, it works fine but the issue is then the struct won't be global. If I declare the struct as mentioned in the code it gives the error message stating that the array size needs to be constant. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: In standard C, the size of a structure must be fixed at compile time.  Even with a _flexible array member_ (FAM), the size of the structure is fixed at compile time — the FAM is simply not counted as part of the size of the structure.  There might be a GCC extension of some sort that allows your code to compile, but you should be extremely careful about using such extensions by accident.  If you want the structure to deal with variable size arrays, then you need to store pointers (and the number of elements in the arrays) in the structure and allocate accordingly.

Comment: @Igor An array is definitely not a pointer

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Can you explain why you want exactly this? Could you share the context?

Comment: You say: _But because of specific requirements, I cannot use pointers and then allocate memory using malloc._  Who is imposing those requirements upon you?  They're a nonsense; you should ask the person imposing the requirement what the alternative is. Whatever they're thinking of is not standard C.  The `+1` complicates things. Otherwise, you could use a pair of structure types: `struct item { int key; int pointer; };` and `struct sample { int n_items; struct item data[]; };` with a FAM (flexible array member) holding the array of data. This may be your best bet; it uses `malloc()`, though.

Comment: Actually, thinking a bit more, maybe the person imposing the requirements is thinking you should use a VLA — variable length array.  As in my [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52125517/allocating-array-size-inside-struct-from-user-input-in-c#comment91202127_52125517), you'd then use an array of the `struct item` type outlined there — and you can allocate that array with a simple definition: `struct item array[size+1];` (or use just `size` — that odd `+1` in the question still has me puzzled).  This avoids pointers and `malloc()` et al.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ The structure type can then be defined at global scope.  The arrays can only be defined in function scope, but the arrays can be passed to other functions accurately (though you'll be using pointers when you do — you can't pass arrays around functions without using pointers, directly or indirectly).

Answer (score 0):

(Just giving examples for the comments.)

I think there are a few typical ways of handling your scenario:

---

**Method 1:**  Global pointer to resources allocated on `main`'s stack (already suggested in other comments):

This variant uses the C99 feature / GCC extension (w.r.t C89) for variably-modified types / variably modified arrays, per Jonathan Leffler's comment.

```
 struct sample *globalSample = NULL;
 int main(){
    //size should be obtained from user input
    size  = 15;

    struct sample{
        int keys[size];
        int pointers[size + 1];
    } mySample;
    globalSample = &mySample;
 }
```

This variant uses `alloca` and "flexible array member". Per Jonathan Leffler's comment below note the change of officially defined syntax for this between C89 and later revisions of the C spec.

```
 struct inner {
     int key;
     int pointer;
 };
 struct sample {
     unsigned int num_allocated;
     struct inner members[1]; // struct hack
 };

 struct sample *globalSample = NULL;
 int main(){
    //size should be obtained from user input
    size  = 15;

    globalSample = alloca((size+1) * sizeof(struct sample));
    globalSample->num_allocated = size;  /*just for book-keeping*/

    globalSample->members[0].key = /*...*/;
    globalSample->members[0].pointer = /*...*/;
    globalSample->members[1].key = /*...  reaching past declared size */
    globalSample->members[1].pointer = /*...*/;

 }
```

---

**Method 2:** Define a max size, and validate user input against it.

```
 #define MAX_ENTRIES 4096
 struct sample{
     int keys[MAX_ENTRIES];
     int pointers[MAX_ENTRIES + 1];
 } globalSample;

 int main(){
    //size should be obtained from user input
    size  = 15;

    if(MAX_ENTRIES < size) { /* error case */ }

 }
```

Comment: Using the `struct inner[1];` notation is invalid on two counts: you've not named the array, and you can only use the inner array as a 'flexible array' by using the 'struct hack', which has officially been undefined behaviour since forever.  In C90, that would have been necessary.  In C99 and beyond, you should use a flexible array member or FAM: `struct inner data[];`.

Comment: Heh, I fixed the missing name on `inner`.  You'll have to forgive my expectation of C89, as I've had to write code that worked with any compiler for a number of years.

Comment: The C90 standard has been obsolete for long enough that its replacement could vote if it were human (C99 will be 19 years old later this year).  Given the speed at which software evolves, it is bordering on criminal that there are C compilers in use that are not basically C99-compliant — indeed, C11 is no longer current (C18 is), but it is 7 years old now.  That said, a large software company — Microsoft — is one of the culprits in this area.

Comment: Agree strongly.